# How to get an intersection point between a curve and a line?

Tags: matlab, intersection

I performed a tensile tests of the material and here is my data. I need to determine the intersection of line with my data, this will give me my yield stress. The data is written in form of:

```
 A = -0.0033   -2.6120
     -0.0037   -2.6309
     -0.0051   -2.6246
     -0.0018   -2.6309
     -0.0030   -2.6120
     -0.0004   -2.5806
     -0.0036   -2.6120
     -0.0026   -2.6120
     -0.0024   -2.5995
     -0.0020   -2.5618... etc.
```

And a line, `y=a*(x-0.2)+b`.

I have tried to with `intersect` function after interpreting the line as a:

```
C =  0  -19.3677
1.0000   48.4377
2.0000  116.2431`
```

But it does not helps. Any suggestions of the problem solution? I have a bunch of an experimental data and would like to write it as a macro. The data has the same pattern of the curve.

Image is here:

[image: intersection]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know how to calculate the intersection of two lines? If so, you can just do this for all the segments that form the curve, and chose the one that makes sense.

Comment: Yes I have seen the solutions for the line to line intersection, where the line was given as an equation, but how I can run the algorithm through the all segments in my data?

Comment: @AlexeyVorobyev: a few options. one is to convert each segment into y=mx+c form.

Answer (score 0):

a) Binary search through your data along the line

b) Locate the segments of data nearest the line

c) Intersect the lines

Binary search will find the mid-point of the approximate curve between the nearest data segments, this is similar to calculating a Bezier curve at any rate.

If accuracy maters, do it analytically.